# C# windows xp sp3 logoff shutdown write to log file

Tags: c#

I want to know how in c# on windows xp service pack 3 do i make a log file that windows has been shutdown. I have a sollution for windows 10 but i just cant find a code for windows xp sp3.
For windows 10 the code is

```
if ((m.LParam.ToInt64() & ENDSESSION_LOGOFF) == ENDSESSION_LOGOFF)
        {
            string path = @"MyTest.txt";

            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                // Create the file.
                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
                {
                    Byte[] info =
                        new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Windows logoff");

                    // Add some information to the file.
                    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
                }
            }
        }
```

and the code is `private const int WM_ENDSESSION = 0x0016;
    private const uint ENDSESSION_LOGOFF = 0x80000000;`

But i cant find on google, msdn or anywhere that for windows xp sp3.
So, if anyone knows a solution please tell me.

Comment: Did you have a look at [SystemEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx)?

Comment: [WM_ENDSESSION message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376889(v=vs.85).aspx), it says that `ENDSESSION_LOGOFF 0x80000000` remains and that [A window receives this message through its WindowProc function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573(v=vs.85).aspx)... probably listening to it will give you the functionality... messages: [uMsg [in] Type: UINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx#system_defined)

Comment: yes but i dosent work in windows service pack 3.

Comment: The [SystemEvents.SessionEnding Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending(v=vs.100).aspx) that I think you should be using states in the platforms section: _Windows 7, Windows Vista SP1 or later, Windows XP SP3..._ I don't have any xp sp3 at hand to try it although

Comment: Yes the form aplication works but im working with inherit NativeWindow so i can override Wndproc in console application.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand really what you want or what your problem is. But you should edit your question and add all the relevant info,e.g. the NativeWindow inheriting part.

Comment: i created a console app that imitates form with this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.wndproc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.         like i said before with normal form works ok that  SystemEvents but in that dosent work.